# Qual erro estou cometendo quando coloco o terceiro item "endereco" no codigo

Tags: php, html

```
<?php   
        include"conectar.php";



        /// codigo para fazer leitura do banco de dados
        /// incluindo ?php echo $cpf ? entre <> na tabela onde ficará o registro



$query="select nome, cpf from associados ";
$stmt=mysqli_query($con,$query);
if($stmt) {

     $today = date("d.m.y");
} else {
     mysqli_rollback($con);
     echo "Transaction rolled back.<br />";
}


while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($stmt) )
{   
                  $cpf = $row['cpf'];
                  $nome = $row['nome'];
                    **$endereco = $row['endereco'];**

}


mysqli_close($con);          
        ?>


onde insiro o resultado da pesquisa
----------------------------------


 <tr>
                    <td> <?php echo $cpf ?> </td>
                    <td><?php echo $nome ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $endereco ?></td></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Dvd obrigado e desculpe pela falta de atenção!

Comment: Dvd mais uma pergunta... qual comando está faltando para ler todas as linhas do banco de dados?

Comment: linhas , exemplo: mais de um nome cadastrado. Com esse código só mostra o ultimo cadastrado queria ler todos os nomes.

Comment: Dá uma olhada [neste link](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_fetch_all.asp)

Comment: Flávio, faz um favor: parece que o site deu um bug. Desmarca a minha resposta e marca de novo por favor.

Comment: Já fiz! Verifique se deu certo!

Comment: Obg! Deu certo mas mesmo assim ficou registrado -15 na reputação. Tem nada não :D... brigadão!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Faltou selecionar a coluna `endereco` na query:

```
$query="select nome, cpf from associados ";
```

Seria:

```
$query="select nome, cpf, endereco from associados";
```